# How To Fetch Image From Flickr to Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7.1

I used This code for fetching images in windows phone 7.1 
 i am a fresher, now only enter into this development. i need help, so plese help me 
 my advance thanks....

C# code is here

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Media;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Xml.Linq;




namespace PhoneApp9
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

        IEnumerable<List<string>> imageURL;
        List<string> lstImageURl;
        Photo P;
        ObservableCollection<Photo> photos;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GetAllPhotos();
        }

        private ImageSource GetImageSource(string fileName)
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileName, UriKind.Absolute));
        }
        private void GetAllPhotos()
        {

            WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
            proxy.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne"));
            proxy.DownloadStringCompleted += new System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler
            (proxy_DownloadStringCompleted);

        }

        void proxy_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            photos = new ObservableCollection<Photo>();
            lstImageURl = new List<string>();
            imageURL = ParseXML(e.Result);
            foreach (var r in imageURL)
            {
                foreach (var a in r)
                {
                    P = new Photo { PhotoSource = GetImageSource(a.ToString()) };
                    photos.Add(P);
                }
            }

            lstImage.ItemsSource = photos;

        }
        private IEnumerable<List<string>> ParseXML(string xmlData)
        {
            XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlData);          
            var photo = from r in doc.Descendants(ns + "entry") 
                        select r.Elements(ns + "link")
                        .Where(f => (string)f.Attribute("rel") == "enclosure")
                        .Select(f => f.Attribute("href").Value).ToList();
            return photo;
        }
    }
}
```

i getting two error in above coding

1.Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'object'.                 'Select' not found.

2.Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'PhoneApp9.XNamespace'

This is the error part

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";

var photo = from r in doc.Descendants(ns + "entry")
```

Comment: Looks like your compiler is getting confused on XNamespace. You probably want System.Xml.Linq.XNamespace, but your error suggests it's found a PhoneApp9.XNamespace in preference. PhoneApp9 looks like the namespace of your app, so have you tried creating your own XNamespace class that it's trying to use here? Is that your intention?

Comment: @PulseLab i have to change the namespace? instead PhoneApp9 Namespace

Comment: @PulseLab can you tell me how to rectify the second error

Comment: How are you even getting to the other error? Are you stepping over the first error on the XNamespace line? In which case I'd ignore the second error until you've fixed the first.

Comment: @PulseLab XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"; instead of this line  i changed this code                                                     XElement el = new XElement("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}Root", "content");
 Console.WriteLine(el); now 1st error is gone but still second error  is displaying thats y i am asking how to rectify second error